# trouble with fulltext search script in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to make a fulltext search using phpmysql but its showing error in mysql_num_rows can you tell me what is the error.i created fulltext index and changed table engine also.

```
   $search=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
   $sql="SELECT * FROM article WHERE MATCH(title, comment) AGAINST ('.$search.')"; 
   $query = mysql_query($sql);

 //Check if any results were returned

 if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){

 //If so, cycle through the results

 while($link = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

  echo("<big><big><a href=show.php?id=$link[id] class=y>$link[title]</a></big></big>    <br>");
  echo('<big>' . $link['comment'] . '</big><br><br>');


//End the while

}}
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the error you are getting?

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Include\searchphp.php on line 61 this is the error it showing

Comment: Do you need the `'` quotes around the $search? Using double quotes usually means that you don't need these. I'm used to using a framework like Codeigniter or my own classes though, so I'm not 100% sure that affects the outcome.

Comment: hi danae i found out my error.i made fulltext for 3 fields but i added two only.now its working fine.i am very thankful for your help

Answer (score 0):

Right after

```
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

add the following

```
if (!$query) echo "<p>".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."</p>";
```

It'll show you the error number and the text of the error message.

If you still don't solve it after reading the error message, your query should read

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM article WHERE MATCH(title, comment) AGAINST ('$search')";
```

but not

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM article WHERE MATCH(title, comment) AGAINST ('.$search.')";
```

Note the dots.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Include\searchphp.php on line 61 this is the error first shown.after adding your script it showed this error Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\wamp\www\Include\searchphp.php on line 60
Warning: mysql_errno() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\Include\searchphp.php on line 60

Comment: Please check again. You should add the line exactly as I told you.

Comment: sorry sanmai i found out the error .i have created a fulltext for 3 fields but i added only two..any way many thanks for the help